# Play Framework 2 ignores https configuration

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I've been trying to configure play framework 2.5.8 to use keystore on custom location with custom purchased certificate. Configuration is as follows (under play section):

```
"server":{
  "https":{
    "keyStore": {
      "path": "/Users/...some_path.../keystore.jks",
      "type": "JKS",
      "password": "some_pass"
    }
  }
```

Everything is local, path reachable, keystore in place.
However, I constantly get debug message:

```
[warn] p.c.s.s.DefaultSSLEngineProvider - Using generated key with self signed certificate for HTTPS. This should not be used in production.
```

Keystore is prepared properly since everything works just fine if I supply keystore and password params as JVM arguments.

Is there anything else that needs to be configured? I even C/P-ed with slight modifications

```
def createSSLContext(applicationProvider: ApplicationProvider): SSLContext
```

method from `DefaultSSLEngineProvider` for testing purposes into one of my controllers to see if execution will reach line 44 (`logger.debug("Using HTTPS keystore at " + file.getAbsolutePath)`) which shouldn't happen in case of wrong configuration, weird keystore file, etc. To my surprise, everything worked properly. However, why Play isn't taking into account configuration from application.conf is beyond me. Unfortunately, supplying keystore params through JVM params is not an option for me in this particular scenario.

Comment: Have you seen the TLS example at http://www.lightbend.com/activator/template/play-tls-example?

Comment: Not sure which part of that example is interesting in my particular case.